# Show div hidden by "display: none" using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The below HTML and JavaScript is working as expected, but I want to make sure I am using this correctly.

I have two divs but only one needs to be displayed depending on the value of `mode`.

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="a-div" style="display: none;">
            <button id="add" class="btnstyle">Add </button>
        </div>
        <div id="d-div" style="display: none;">
            <button id="delete" class="btnstyle">Delete</button>
        </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
//$("#a-div").hide();
//$("#d-div").hide();

var mode = 'add';
//var mode = 'delete';
if (mode === 'add') {
    $("#a-div").show();
} else {
    $("#d-div").show();
}
```

This is giving me expected results. Is there a better way of reversing the `style="display: none"` attribute?

Comment: Why do you have “smart quotes” `‘’` in your code instead of straight quotes: `''`?

Comment: You're definitely doing it correctly. `show()` is designed for jobs like this.

Comment: @ Xufox I wrote this sample code in a word document (bad choice)

Answer (score 1):

Your current code should be working fine, but there are many ways of solving this problem. I would recommend using jQuerys [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$("#a-div").toggle(mode === "add");
$("#a-div").toggle(mode === "delete");
```

Alternatively, you could give them the id´s `add-div` and `delete-div` and make one of them visible like this:

```
$("#" + mode + "-div").show();
```

Comment: It's always a good idea to use the display:none. Otherwise you often see the content flash on the screen when the page loads but before the document.ready event fires and hides the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$("#a-div").toggle();
```

Alternatively;
`.show()` / `.hide()`
`.fadeIn()` / `fadeOut()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the display property of the inline style attribute.

Like this...

```
var mode = 'add';

if (mode === 'add') {
    $("#a-div")[0].style.display = 'block';
} else {
    $("#d-div")[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Or you can use something like `inherit` instead of `block`.

Comment: You can't use `.style` with jQuery objects, you have to use `.css()`.

Comment: Yes you can. The first item of the object is an element just like `document.getElementById ()` would give you. All other functions do more work that is, in my opinion, unnecessary.

Comment: You didn't have `[0]` when I wrote that comment. That returns the DOM object contained in the jQuery object, so of course you can then use DOM properties.

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly set `display` to `block`? Isn't just calling `show()` as in the original question enough, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Barmar You implied it was impossible using jQuery's `$()` function entirely. I made a typo, big deal. It's possible is what matters.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it was a typo, it looked like a conceptual error. You wouldn't be the first poster to try using a DOM property/method on a jQuery object or vice versa.

Comment: @Anders As I say, the `.show ()` function does a lot of other things, that are simply unnecessary for such a simple, well supported task. For example, `.show ()` supports animations, and keeps track of what the property was set to, so it can set it back to the initial state, among other things.

Comment: @Barmar No problems :-)

Answer (score 0):

There's several methods to do this (like you can see in other answers) but i think the `show()` function is enough and do the work in your case.

You can also use `css()` method of JQuery like following :

```
$("#a-div").css('display','block');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to move the styles to css:

html:

```
    <div id="a-div" class="notdisplayed">
        <button id="add" class="btnstyle">Add </button>
    </div>
    <div id="d-div" class="notdisplayed">
        <button id="delete" class="btnstyle">Delete</button>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.notDisplayed {display:none;}
```

Script:

```
$("#a-div").addClass("notDisplayed");
$("#d-div").removeClass("notDisplayed");
```

This method is more general than show/hide, as it can be extended to any style rule.